# Google drive SDK, get files uploaded by other user with my app

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I want to create PHP website for groups where users will be able to upload files using Google Drive and share this files with other group users. But is it possible to get other user files without setting file permission to read by anyone? It would be great if i could add new joined user's email to file read permission but owner of this file would have to authenticate to make it possible? I will be very thankful for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a permission that is scoped to a Google Group, instead of an individual user. More information on [Share Files developer guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-sharing#types_and_values). Users won't be prompted to re-share their files when new users join the group however.

Comment: Thank you for answer but that is not what I am looking for. I will not use google group but I will create groups on my website and database. Lets say I will create website like Google Groups and i need to share files between groups users. Am i able to do this? Or maybe will I in future? :D

Comment: You can do that, you'll just need to write the code to detect new users and then add them to each file that's been shared with the group. The API won't do it for you.

Comment: But how can I change file permissions when owner of the file is offline?

Comment: You can request a refresh token when the user goes through the OAuth flow. The refresh token allows for offline access.